# How to troubleshoot mislabeling of provinces in my shapefile in r?

Tags: r, projection, shapefile, tmap

I have a shapefile of the Philippines that has all the correct labels of each provinces. After removing some of the provinces I won't be using, aggregating the data into a single data frame, and then attaching my covariates to the shapefile I run into trouble. Using tmap to create some maps, the provinces are mislabeled and therefore, different data is applied to different provinces I am doing a spatial-temporal analysis with this data, so it's important the provinces are in the correct locations.

I have tried retrojecting some of the shapefile, but it doesn't seem to work.

```r
#reading in shapefile
shp <- readOGR(".","province.csv")

#removing provinces not in data from shapefile                         
myshp82=shp
shp@data$prov=as.character(shp@data$prov)

ind=shp@data$prov%in% mydata$prov

shp.subset=shp[ind,]


#attaching covariates to shapefile for plotting, myagg is my data frame. 
#The shape files are divided in four different time periods. 

myagg_time1=myagg[myagg$period==1,]
myagg_time2=myagg[myagg$period==2,]
myagg_time3=myagg[myagg$period==3,]
myagg_time4=myagg[myagg$period==4,]

myshptime1=myshptime2=myshptime3=myshptime4=shp
myshptime1@data=merge(myshptime1@data, myagg_time1, by='prov',all.x=TRUE)
myshptime2@data=merge(myshptime2@data, myagg_time2, by='prov',all.x=TRUE)
myshptime3@data=merge(myshptime3@data, myagg_time3, by='prov',all.x=TRUE)
myshptime4@data=merge(myshptime4@data, myagg_time4, by='prov',all.x=TRUE)

#desc maps. Here's the code I've been using for one of the maps. 
Per1= tm_shape(myshptime1)+
  tm_polygons(c('total_incomeMed','IRA_depMean','pov'), title=c('Total Income', 'IRA', 'Poverty (%)'))+
  tm_facets(sync = TRUE, ncol=3)
```

```r
#sample data from my data sheet "myagg". First column is provinces. 

                     period   counts    total_income_MED       IRA_depMean
Agusan del Norte.1     1       2          119.33052              0.8939136
Agusan del Norte.2     2       0          280.96928              0.8939136
Agusan del Norte.3     3       1          368.30082              0.8939136      
Agusan del Norte.4     4       0          368.30082              0.8950379  
Aklan.5                1       0          129.63132              0.8716863  
Aklan.6                2       3          282.95535              0.8716863          
Aklan.7                3       3          460.29969              0.8716863      
Aklan.8                4       0          460.29969              0.8437920
Albay.9                1       0          280.12221              0.8696165
Albay.10               2       3          453.05098              0.8696165
Albay.11               3       1          720.40732              0.8696165
Albay.12               4       0          720.40732              0.8254676
```

Essentially the above tmap code creates three maps for this time period side-by-side for each of the different covariates ('total_incomeMed','IRA_depMean','pov'). This is happening, but the provinces are mislabeled and the data is tied to the name of the province. I just need the provinces properly labeled!

Sorry if this doesn't make sense. Happy to clarify more if needed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: I added above. Let me know if you need anymore info. Thanks!